# Finding all possible combinations of Range to reach a given sum

Tags: vb.net-2010

Could you please help me to find the combination of range values to reach a given sum and highlight them or move them to new sheet.

In the below mention address the answer given by "CodingQuant" working fine but i want this to adopt to worksheet ranges and highlight them or move them in new sheet.

"[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)"

Kindly advise.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards,
Rahaman

Comment: Could you please add what have you tried to your question ?

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you for attending my request,I am unable to paste the code which i tried, my question is finding the sum of ranges(Values) withing the column which equal to target cell value and highlight them. Kindly advise.

Comment: Hi, Rahaman. StackOverflow gave me your question for review. My comment was what I thought could improve your question. I have no idea how to answer it :)

Comment: Hi Andrei, No problem & Thank you for everything. actullay i was trying to find combination of sums to match the target value in Vba.